# How do I deal with conflicting enpoints in Spring RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint defined like this:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/dogs/{dogId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Dog getDogById(@NotBlank @PathVariable("dogId") String dogId);
```

I want to define a new endpoint like this in the same @RestController:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/dogs/collars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    List<Collar> getAllDogCollarsByQuery(@RequestParam String dogName, @RequestParam String dogYear);
```

Problem is whenever I try to call the new endpoint like so:

```
/dogs/collars?dogName=Bingo&dogYear=11
```

Spring will route my call to the getDogById method and maps rest of my endpoint url to @PathVariable.

I tried adding another path to the endpoint so the endpoint will look like this:

```
GET /dogs/collars/search
```

But I get a HTTP 415 error when I try to call it.

Is there a way to resolve conflicts like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that adding `consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE` to the endpoint solved this problem.
Endpoint definition now looks like this:

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/dogs/collars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    List<Collar> getAllDogCollarsByQuery(@RequestParam String dogName, @RequestParam String dogYear);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex to resolve this issue.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/dogs/{dogId:^[1-9][0-9]*}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Dog getDogById(@NotBlank @PathVariable("dogId") String dogId);

@GetMapping(value = "/dogs/collars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    List<Collar> getAllDogCollarsByQuery(@RequestParam String dogName, @RequestParam String dogYear);
```

Comment: This assumes dogId is numerical

Comment: Yes, otherwise, the first declared api will take priority. You can also design the regex to mimic your ids. I don't know what kind of ids you're using so i assumed its integers